# Adding Custom Pushpin to Bing Maps in Silverlight

Tags: xaml, bing, silverlight-5.0

I am very new to Bing Maps Concept

Requirement: Need to Design a Bing Map with Custom Pushpin and many layers on the Bing Map
Work Done: Created a Bing map with a Key and 2 DLL's, Added multiple Pushpins, Added a shape on the map using MapPolygon

Issues:

1. I need to add Custom Pushpins to the Bing Map(I have an Image in my Project folder which I need to show on the Bing Map when the Location is specified).  I have gone through many links and none worked for me.  So plz tell me the method to follow to show the Custom Pushpin on the Bing Map.
2. I need to add multiple layers on the Bing Maps and I have least knowledge about it.  So please guide me about the Layering Concept in Silverlight Bing Maps.

Badly need help :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the [interactive SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/maps/isdk/silverlight/#MapControlInteractiveSdk.Tutorials.UIElements.TutorialPositionLocation) that Microsoft provides?  It helped me out.

It seems that you need only place a `MapLayer` and place `Pushpin` controls in it.  You use the `MapLayer.Position` attached property to pin down anything within that map layer to the map; so that when the user moves the map it says.  This attached property is of the type `Location` which is a type that is proprietary to the Bing Map control that contains both a Longitude (double) and a Latitude (double) value.  If you need to bind a collection of said locations than you can use a `MapItemsControl` inside of a `MapLayer` bind its `ItemsSource` property to your collections.  You can also create data template; just remember that your template root must use the `MapLayer.Position` attached property to specify its location on the map.  This can be bound to any `Location`-typed value.

```
    <UserControl x:Class="MapControlInteractiveSdk.Tutorials.DataBinding.TutorialMapItemsControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    xmlns:t="clr-namespace:MapControlInteractiveSdk.Tutorials.DataBinding"
    xmlns:m="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maps.MapControl;assembly=Microsoft.Maps.MapControl">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="LogoTemplate">
            <!-- This doesn't have to be a pushpin control - it can be anything just apply 
                    the "m:MapLayer.Position" property to whatever is the root of the
                    template.
               -->
            <m:Pushpin m:MapLayer.Position="{Binding Location}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <m:Map CredentialsProvider="Your Key">
            <m:MapLayer>
                <m:MapItemsControl x:Name="ListOfItems"
                            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource LogoTemplate}"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding MyLocalizedEntities}">
                </m:MapItemsControl>
            </m:MapLayer>
            <m:MapLayer>
                <!-- You can have content in multiple layers: Latter layers are infront of former ones. -->
            </m:MapLayer>
        </m:Map>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```